# Exporting encrypted folders for NFS

Tags: encryption, nfs

Have used NFS for quite a while on 9.10 and 10.04 to access folders on PCs on the LAN. I recently chose the 'Encrypt home partition' option when installing Ubuntu 10.04 on a new PC.

Now when I attempt to Export a folder that is on the encrypted home partition, Exports throws up a message that the folder cannot be exported.

I have searched the web high and low and found a couple of other users with the same problem, but no resolution.

I can successfully export folders that are not on encrypted partitions.

Is NFS not compatible with folders on Ubuntu encrypted home partitions?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel-level NFS server (`nfs-kernel-server`) does not work well with custom filesystems like FUSE, if I remember correctly. Instead, you should give `unfs3` a try.

I haven't used `unfs3` and can't promise anything, but I believe *anything* is better than `nfs-kernel-server` for serving from non-traditional filesystems.

Comment: I am using nfs-kernel-server. Do I need to uninstall unfs3 first? I only converted from Windows about 12 months ago, so still getting my head around Linux.

Comment: @sealevel: No, you need to uninstall `nfs-kernel-server` and install `unfs3` instead. :-D

Comment: Update your question and answers as you ask each other comments with the relevant information, that way people who run across this question/answer get the updated information right upfront. See the FAQ: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: @Jorge: Done. :-)

Comment: Thanks Jorge, Yeah there was a typo in the above post regarding installing. I uninstalled ...server and installed unfs3 but still no luck. "sudo exportfs -ra" throws up a message; "exportfs not found"

Comment: SOLVED: Sort of, finally found a SAMBA guide to suite Ubuntu 10.04 and that allowed me to access the encrypted partition.